# Randomly change javascript popup code

Tags: javascript, jquery, random

I have three different pop up ads javascript code uploaded on my site. I want to make a Javascript program that will randomly change one each time a page is loaded. How would I do this?

**Script 1**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var uid = '12946';
    var wid = '23707';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.pop.net/pop.js"></script>
```

**Script 2**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var uid = '22333';
    var wid = '234333';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.pop.net/pop.js"></script>
```

**Script 3**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var uid = '14444';
    var wid = '23444';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.pop.net/pop.js"></script>
```

Comment: and where is the code.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar its javascript code 

`1)
<script type="text/javascript">
var uid = '12946';
var wid = '23707';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.pop.net/pop.js"></script>

2)
<script type="text/javascript">
var uid = '22333';
var wid = '234333';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.pop.net/pop.js"></script>

3)
<script type="text/javascript">
var uid = '14444';
var wid = '23444';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.pop.net/pop.js"></script>`


problem is open three popup same time 
i need open one pop up every reload

Comment: can you share the fiddle

Comment: @MilindAnantwar A fiddle is not necessary.  We just need the script posted in the question (not a comment) in a readable manner.

Comment: @Archer: this is not making much sense to me(only the js part shared)

Comment: The script url doesn't seem to exist.  Is that correct?

Comment: @MilindAnantwar

some one edit main post and add javascript code
please see

Comment: @MilindAnantwar sir check this its banner code but i need full javascript code change
http://jsfiddle.net/8GwQh/

Comment: @Sonia: its not clear what you want. can you elaborate

Comment: @MilindAnantwar

see sir
http://jsfiddle.net/8GwQh/5/

above is just example what i need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will randomly pick one of the 3 combinations you gave us...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    var uid = ["12946", "22333", "14444"][i];
    var wid = ["23707", "234333", "23444"][i];
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.pop.net/pop.js"></script>
```

Comment: sir  possible to add full code change ?

like 

http://jsfiddle.net/8GwQh/

above i found but its for baner code

Comment: sir its not working if ihave different javascript popup code

please help me to done change full code not uid

Comment: Sorry @Sonia, but what has that fiddle got to do with this question?  There's absolutely no commonality whatsoever.

Comment: Sir in your code just change UID and WID

what if i have 3 different company pop code and different java script ?

Comment: Do you mean that the javascript source can change as well?

Comment: Yes please see main post i edit code different all three

Comment: Please ask a new question instead.  What you originally asked has been answered and this site is meant for everyone, so people coming here in future may be looking for help with the question that we've actually been answering.  I've rolled it back to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var random=Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1; 
if(random==1){
    var uid = '12946';
    var wid = '23707';
}else if(random==2){
    var uid = '22333';
    var wid = '234333';
}else{
     var uid = '14444';
     var wid = '23444';
} 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.pop.net/pop.js"></script>
```

Comment: see sir
http://jsfiddle.net/8GwQh/5/

above url is just example what i need

i don't want just uid change i need full code change every reload

Comment: @Sonia: you need to follow the same approach.

Comment: Sir in your code just change UID and WID what if i have 3 different company pop code and different java script ?

please i need full javascript change on every reload

Comment: Then write the code in three diffrent files. and randomly load any of them.